# Where to input Wordpress plugin script so it loads as same time as content?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-plugins, lightbox

Detailed edit of previous question:

If a plugin needs to load at the same time as the content on the Wordpress page in order for it to work, where can I input the code? Currently, the plugin is loading after the content loads, and I have to input a script so it runs at the same time as the content.

Plugin developer suggested I put the following code in my scripts:

`if(typeof doLightBox !== 'undefined' && typeof jQuery !== 'undefined'){
   doLightBox();
}`

I have put it at the end the following file, to no effect:

http://example.com/wp-content/themes/exampletheme/assets/scripts/script.js?ver=1

Any ideas?

---

Have tried multiple ways of fixing a problem with a Wordpress jQuery Lightbox plugin that does not load correctly. The length of time allowed after the initial page load makes no difference - whether the page has loaded for 1 second or 15 seconds: the first image that is clicked on, not necessarily the first in the gallery, loads as a normal /imagename.jpg page.  Then when the visitor clicks "back" then reloads the same image, the lightbox plugin "kicks-in" and works. It is as though an image needs to be clicked on to activate the plugin on the page.

Tried the following:

Smush.it plugin for all images, thinking they were too large;

Plugin Organizer plugin and ordered jQuery Lightbox plugin to load first;

Used W3TC to clear all page caches.

None of these seem to do the job.

Any ideas?

Comment: Also just tried adding the function `function doLightBox(){` Custom JavaScript to the Main part of the WP Dashboard  (cannot post all the script in comment box). Does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: Can you show me the syntax of images HTml, u want to be in Lightbox

Comment: Don't know if I 100% understood what you said but this is what I put in my HTML editor in WP (some shortcodes here): `<h6><a href="/chris-engman-biography" target="_blank">VIEW BIOGRAPHY</a></h6>
[gallery link="file" group="ENGMAN" columns="4" ids="908,909,922,913,911,910,914,919,920,921,918,917,916,915"]`

Comment: I'm talking about the markup, that is generated in frontend, also did u checked console for errors and if js is being loaded or not?

Comment: Hmmm here is the site: http://clair.me/portfolio/chris-engman/   Warning: contains fine art that might be NSFW.

Comment: Don't know if its on your end only, It works absolutely awesome for me  on firefox, Chrome, in the first click itself the image opens up in Lightbox

Comment: Strange, it still does not load correctly for me. Maybe it is a connection problem? I do not have fibre optic; perhaps you do?

Comment: No I don't have any fibre optics dude, its a normal Internet